# Successful su for user by root in /var/log/auth.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

I have this sorts of entries in my /var/log/auth.log:

```
Apr  3 12:32:23 machine_name su[1521]: Successful su for user1 by root
Apr  3 12:32:23 machine_name su[1654]: Successful su for user2 by root
Apr  3 12:32:24 machine_name su[1772]: Successful su for user3 by root
```

Situation:

- All users are real accounts in /etc/passwd;
- None of the users has its own crontab;
- All of those users are logged in the machine some time ago via SSH or No Machine - time varies from few minutes to few hours;
- no cron jobs are scheduled to run at that time, anacron is removed;
- I can see similar entries for other days and other times. The common part is the users are logged in when it appears. It does not appear during login, but some time afterwards.

This machine has similar setup with few others but it is the only one where I see these entries.

What causes them?
Thanks

Edit: I managed to narrow it down. I believe it is caused by `cron @reboot`. The funny part is - it runs "something" only for the users logged in right before the reboot. I checked `/var/spool/cron`, `crontab -u <username> -l`, `grep -r @reboot /etc /var` and can't see anything.

How I could run `cron @reboot` manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find the source of the `su` launches, `auditd` will track them for you. See here: https://superuser.com/a/222924

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct, although it did not solve my problem. However, I find it useful overall. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It says [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/177189/550380) that the login program is run by root. When a user opens a session it is open by root, then root su-es to that user, which is consistent with the log entries you have (root becoming user through su)